# Green logic fault in Braid

Tags: braid

In Braid, chapter four (Time & Place), "Hunt!", the hunt registers for the monsters (on the door in the upper right) has a greenish hue, which basically means it stays invariant over time. But then, when you go left-right, the time changes, so if a monster revives, a cross in the door register goes off, which means the register is not invariant over time. Why is this?

[image: braid - chapter 4 - time and place - hunt!]

Answer (score 6):

This is a good question, and brings out a few of the subtleties of the visual clues in this game.

Notice that the hunt registers for the monsters appear in two places:

- Small ones on the door in the upper right (door a greenish hue)
- Large ones centered at the top of the screen (registers DO NOT have a greenish hue)

The large hunt registers centered at the top of the screen are what matter. The crosses on the door are only there to indicate that opening the door is tied to completing the large hunt registers.

Small crosses on the door are ***NOT*** invariant over time. But *the door itself* ***IS*** invariant over time.

Try opening the door, and moving left so the time changes. When a monster revives and a cross goes off at the top of the screen, the door will stay open. That is why the door has a greenish hue.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, the checkboxes on the door do not need to be there at all. Everything is calculated using the HUD at the top, so all 6 monsters need to be killed without being revived in order to unlock the door. Once the door is unlocked, then it becomes time-independent, which is how the game was designed.

In other words, the issue is not green logic fault, but rather the superfluous nature of having the checkboxes on the door itself when the HUD already fulfills that purpose.